# tabelView func explanation

Tags: swift, tableview

I have encountered the following func while studying UItableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, ....
```

I have never encountered a function that is using its own name in the variable section.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Please read the [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) chapter of the Swift book. Then update your question to clarify what confusion you are having. There's nothing special about table view data source and delegate methods in regards to function naming.

Comment: FYI - Look at any protocol named `UIxxxDelegate` or `UIxxxDataSource` for many examples of this pattern.

Comment: There is a difference between the name of a function and the name of a parameter of that function...

Comment: Cristik can you explain a bit more ??

Comment: @Sara You just asked for more of an explanation. The link I provided gives you that information which is why I suggested that you read it first. Most likely you will answer your own question. At a minimum you should learn enough to be able to clarify your question (which is why I suggested you edit your question with more specific details after you read the link).

Comment: If you talk about `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, the signature is `tableView(_ :cellForRowAt)` It's not only `tableView`, so it's not the variable and the name at the same point.

Comment: @Sara `tableView` is a just a name, like Sara, that can be used in multiple places: a function name, a parameter label, a parameter name, a class name, etc. In the context you ask, it's a coincidence (or not? see Objc definition) that Apple chose to use the same name for the function and it's first argument.

Answer (score 1):

In your function the first `tableView` is the name of the function, the second one is a name given to one of its parameters.

A simple function could be declared as follows:

1. keyword `func`
2. he given name of the function
3. opening parenthesis `(`
4. parameter names (if any),  each of them followed by colons `:` and then its type, all are separated by commas `,`
5. closing parenthesis `)`
6. If this function returns a value then :

   - an arrow `->` which is just a <kbd>-</kbd> and a <kbd>></kbd>
   - a return type
7. opening curly brace `{`
8. Here is the body of your function

   - If this function returns a value then use the `return` keyword followed by the value you want to return.
9. Finally a closing brace `}`

That would define the ***signature*** of this function: what makes a function from another function is 
 - its name,
 - the number and names of its parameters and their types,
 - And its return type.

(We could add the object it belongs to, if it throws or not, ...)

Here is an example of a function that takes a `String` and returns another. You could try it in a playground in Xcode:

```
//Declare the function
func sayHiTo(person: String) -> String {
    let greeting = "Hello " + person
    return greeting
}
//Invoke it
sayHiTo(person: "Sara")     //"Hello Sara"
```

Can you see how we invoked the function in the last line: `sayHiTo(person: "Sara")`? To call a function follow these steps:

- put the name of the function (same as `2.` from the previous list)
- opening parenthesis `(`
- parameter names (if any),  each of them followed by colons `:` and then its type.

We could use `_` before a parameter name if we want to invoke a function without stating the name parameter:

```
func laugh(_ s: String) -> String {
    return s + s
}

laugh("Ha")   //HaHa
```

And nothing would go wrong if the name of a parameter is the same as the name of the function:

```
func name(name: String) {
    print(name)
}

name(name: "Katie")  //prints Katie in the console
```

Now, let's have a look at this function signature:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

As you can see,

- `tableView` is the name of the function
- The second `tableView` is the name of its first parameter
- The underscore `_` means you don't need to mention the parameter name when invoking this function
- `UITableView` is the type of the first parameter
- `cellForRowAt` is the *external name* of the second parameter
- `indexPath` is the *internal name* of the second parameter
- `IndexPath`is the type of the second parameter
- `-> UITableViewCell` means that this function returns an instance of type `UITableViewCell`

A question you might ask: why use the same name of a function and a parameter? And the answer is :

- It's a convention that all data source function in [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource). It is easier to remember, and gets even more convenient with Xcode autocomplete feature.
- Plus, it really helpful to have a reference to the tableView you are using, and there is no clearer name than `tableView` for that parameter.